# Can I dynamically assign the image src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have a Json object.

```
{"prev":["","demo\/medium\/Web081112_P001_medium.jpg"],"curr":["demo\/medium\/Web081112_P002_medium.jpg","demo\/medium\/Web081112_P003_medium.jpg"],"next":["demo\/medium\/Web081112_P004_medium.jpg","demo\/medium\/Web081112_P005_medium.jpg"]}
```

You can see that the Json object structure is like the following:

```
prev img1, img2
curr img1, img2
next img1, img2
```

The img is either an image path or " " .

What I would like to achieve is , there are six image link

```
    <img src ="....."> and I would like define each of it to  <img id= "prevIMG2" src =""> 
And assign the prev img2 to that <img id= "prevIMG2" src ="demo/medium/Web081112_P001_medium.jpg">
```

For those with no value, it do not assign any `<img src="">`

How can I achieve  this using jquery ? Thank you

What I used to change the image path

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "scandir.php",
        data: "page=5",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        if($.trim(this[0]) !== '')
        $('#prevL').attr('src',data);
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to remove the src from those 6 which had a source? Are you aware that ID's are supposed to be unique?

Comment: sure, you can see that in my question the ID are prevIMG1, prevIMG2, currIMG1, currIMG2...

Comment: The goal of this :  parser the json object to differinate different img, assign the image path to those six <img src>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I hope no prob using Jquery , right ??,then you can use

```
$('#IDofTheImage').attr('src','string path value extracted from json response');
```

Comment: Can I prevent <img src="    ">  In case the value from json is " " ?

Comment: @user782104 $.trim() the value and compare against empty strings before adding the image source. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VZ9D7/

Comment: Thanks, Also, How to let the machine know which is prev[0] and have it assign to the img id ="prevL" and which is prev [1] and have it assign to img id ="prevR"?